# Mysql - cross table 'where' with records

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

that´s my following situation:

Table: selection

```
selection_id | group_id | selection_group_id |  
------------------------------------------------
     1            1              1
```

Table: selectors

```
selector_id | selection_id | name | index
------------------------------------------
     1             1         Step1   0 
     2             1         Step2   1 
     3             1         Step3   2
```

**My question:** How can i find out the unique 'selection_id'  of the selectors with the  conjoint information "Step1,Step2,Step3" which construct a selection unit ?

I try to describe it more precisely: I need a routine which get the unique 'selection_id' from the 3 selectors which be connected with the same 'selection_id'. My informationen are the 'names' of the selectors and the 'index'. The names of the 'selectors' can occur frequently but the contiguous index of the selectors are unique. –

Comment: this is a one liner sql join select. What's that about three steps?

Comment: The steps represent a setup where the 'selection' is the parent of the selectors and it can contains unlimited childs 'selector'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded my solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdbba/20/0

```
SELECT selections.selection_id FROM `prstshp_productsort_groups_selections` selections 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  `prstshp_productsort_groups_selectors` s3
                WHERE s3.name = "Muskelaufbau" AND s3.index = 0 AND s3.selection_id = selections.selection_id)
AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  `prstshp_productsort_groups_selectors` s4
                WHERE s4.name = "Mesomorph" AND s4.index = 1 AND s4.selection_id = selections.selection_id)
AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  `prstshp_productsort_groups_selectors` s5
                WHERE s5.name = "Männlich" AND s5.index = 2 AND s5.selection_id = selections.selection_id)
AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  `prstshp_productsort_groups_selectors` s6
                WHERE s6.name = "25-40" AND s6.index = 3 AND s6.selection_id = selections.selection_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` - not sure you even need to `JOIN` your tables:

```
SELECT selection_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM selectors
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4609f/3).

And to find out the unique selection_id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Selection_ID
FROM (
  SELECT selection_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) gc
  FROM selectors
  ) t
WHERE gc = 'Step1,Step2,Step3'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4609f/13

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your idea but that´s not possible becouse i have lots of other selectors which have the same name and also different order in the table.

Comment: Can you show sample input and desired results?  I'm still a little confused about your desired results.  Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: This is going to depend on how you expect to set this up.  Dynamic SQL would be an option.  However, this particular query returns the result you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdbba/18 -- Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need aggregation with a `having` clause.  For example:

```
select selector_id
from selectors s
group by selector_id
having max(case when name = 'Step1' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when name = 'Step2' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when name = 'Step3' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when name in ('Step1', 'Step2', 'Step3') then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

I find this method to be the most general . . . using the `having` statement with various conditions based on conditional max's.  There are some other ways of expressing this, such as:

```
select selector_id
from selectors s
group by selector_id
having count(distinct name) = 3 and
       max(case when name in ('Step1', 'Step2', 'Step3') then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

that look simpler, but are not as general a form.

Comment: I try to describe it more precisely: I need a routine which get the unique 'selection_id' from the 3 selectors which be connected with the same 'selection_id'. My informationen are the 'names' of the selectors and the 'index'. The names of the 'selectors' can occur frequently but the contiguous `index` of the selectors are unique.

Comment: I think some variation of the solution provided here should get you what you're after. If not, consider providing a thorough data set (as a sqlfiddle and/or set of DDLs) for us to play with.